# Битрикс. Проблема отображения элементов каталога

Tags: php, битрикс

Использую комплексный компонент каталог. Изменил под себя шаблон catalog.section. Первые три элемента выводятся нормально[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все следующие элементы не попадают в ul и выводятся отдельными li за пределами блока.

```html
<? if (!defined('B_PROLOG_INCLUDED') || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();

use \Bitrix\Main\Localization\Loc;

/**
 * @global CMain $APPLICATION
 * @var array $arParams
 * @var array $arResult
 * @var CatalogSectionComponent $component
 * @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this
 * @var string $templateName
 * @var string $componentPath
 *
 *  _________________________________________________________________________
 * | Attention!
 * | The following comments are for system use
 * | and are required for the component to work correctly in ajax mode:
 * | <!-- items-container -->
 * | <!-- pagination-container -->
 * | <!-- component-end -->
 */

$this->setFrameMode(true);

if (!empty($arResult['NAV_RESULT']))
{
 $navParams =  array(
  'NavPageCount' => $arResult['NAV_RESULT']->NavPageCount,
  'NavPageNomer' => $arResult['NAV_RESULT']->NavPageNomer,
  'NavNum' => $arResult['NAV_RESULT']->NavNum
 );
}
else
{
 $navParams = array(
  'NavPageCount' => 1,
  'NavPageNomer' => 1,
  'NavNum' => $this->randString()
 );
}

$showTopPager = false;
$showBottomPager = false;
$showLazyLoad = false;

if ($arParams['PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT'] > 0 && $navParams['NavPageCount'] > 1)
{
 $showTopPager = $arParams['DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER'];
 $showBottomPager = $arParams['DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER'];
 $showLazyLoad = $arParams['LAZY_LOAD'] === 'Y' && $navParams['NavPageNomer'] != $navParams['NavPageCount'];
}

$templateLibrary = array('popup', 'ajax', 'fx');
$currencyList = '';

if (!empty($arResult['CURRENCIES']))
{
 $templateLibrary[] = 'currency';
 $currencyList = CUtil::PhpToJSObject($arResult['CURRENCIES'], false, true, true);
}

$templateData = array(
 'TEMPLATE_LIBRARY' => $templateLibrary,
 'CURRENCIES' => $currencyList
);
unset($currencyList, $templateLibrary);

$elementEdit = CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arParams['IBLOCK_ID'], 'ELEMENT_EDIT');
$elementDelete = CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arParams['IBLOCK_ID'], 'ELEMENT_DELETE');
$elementDeleteParams = array('CONFIRM' => GetMessage('CT_BCS_TPL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM'));

$positionClassMap = array(
 'left' => 'product-item-label-left',
 'center' => 'product-item-label-center',
 'right' => 'product-item-label-right',
 'bottom' => 'product-item-label-bottom',
 'middle' => 'product-item-label-middle',
 'top' => 'product-item-label-top'
);

$discountPositionClass = '';
if ($arParams['SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT'] === 'Y' && !empty($arParams['DISCOUNT_PERCENT_POSITION']))
{
 foreach (explode('-', $arParams['DISCOUNT_PERCENT_POSITION']) as $pos)
 {
  $discountPositionClass .= isset($positionClassMap[$pos]) ? ' '.$positionClassMap[$pos] : '';
 }
}

$labelPositionClass = '';
if (!empty($arParams['LABEL_PROP_POSITION']))
{
 foreach (explode('-', $arParams['LABEL_PROP_POSITION']) as $pos)
 {
  $labelPositionClass .= isset($positionClassMap[$pos]) ? ' '.$positionClassMap[$pos] : '';
 }
}

$arParams['~MESS_BTN_BUY'] = $arParams['~MESS_BTN_BUY'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCS_TPL_MESS_BTN_BUY');
$arParams['~MESS_BTN_DETAIL'] = $arParams['~MESS_BTN_DETAIL'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCS_TPL_MESS_BTN_DETAIL');
$arParams['~MESS_BTN_COMPARE'] = $arParams['~MESS_BTN_COMPARE'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCS_TPL_MESS_BTN_COMPARE');
$arParams['~MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE'] = $arParams['~MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCS_TPL_MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE');
$arParams['~MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET'] = $arParams['~MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCS_TPL_MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET');
$arParams['~MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE'] = $arParams['~MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCS_TPL_MESS_PRODUCT_NOT_AVAILABLE');
$arParams['~MESS_SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY'] = $arParams['~MESS_SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCS_CATALOG_SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY');
$arParams['~MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_MANY'] = $arParams['~MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_MANY'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCS_CATALOG_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_MANY');
$arParams['~MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FEW'] = $arParams['~MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FEW'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCS_CATALOG_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FEW');

$arParams['MESS_BTN_LAZY_LOAD'] = $arParams['MESS_BTN_LAZY_LOAD'] ?: Loc::getMessage('CT_BCS_CATALOG_MESS_BTN_LAZY_LOAD');

$generalParams = array(
 'SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => $arParams['SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT'],
 'PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE' => $arParams['PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE'],
 'SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY' => $arParams['SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY'],
 'RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FACTOR' => $arParams['RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FACTOR'],
 'MESS_SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY' => $arParams['~MESS_SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY'],
 'MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_MANY' => $arParams['~MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_MANY'],
 'MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FEW' => $arParams['~MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FEW'],
 'SHOW_OLD_PRICE' => $arParams['SHOW_OLD_PRICE'],
 'USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY' => $arParams['USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY'],
 'PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE' => $arParams['PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE'],
 'ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION' => $arParams['ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION'],
 'ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET' => $arParams['ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET'],
 'PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE' => $arParams['PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE'],
 'SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP' => $arParams['SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP'],
 'DISPLAY_COMPARE' => $arParams['DISPLAY_COMPARE'],
 'COMPARE_PATH' => $arParams['COMPARE_PATH'],
 'COMPARE_NAME' => $arParams['COMPARE_NAME'],
 'PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION' => $arParams['PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION'],
 'PRODUCT_BLOCKS_ORDER' => $arParams['PRODUCT_BLOCKS_ORDER'],
 'LABEL_POSITION_CLASS' => $labelPositionClass,
 'DISCOUNT_POSITION_CLASS' => $discountPositionClass,
 'SLIDER_INTERVAL' => $arParams['SLIDER_INTERVAL'],
 'SLIDER_PROGRESS' => $arParams['SLIDER_PROGRESS'],
 '~BASKET_URL' => $arParams['~BASKET_URL'],
 '~ADD_URL_TEMPLATE' => $arResult['~ADD_URL_TEMPLATE'],
 '~BUY_URL_TEMPLATE' => $arResult['~BUY_URL_TEMPLATE'],
 '~COMPARE_URL_TEMPLATE' => $arResult['~COMPARE_URL_TEMPLATE'],
 '~COMPARE_DELETE_URL_TEMPLATE' => $arResult['~COMPARE_DELETE_URL_TEMPLATE'],
 'TEMPLATE_THEME' => $arParams['TEMPLATE_THEME'],
 'USE_ENHANCED_ECOMMERCE' => $arParams['USE_ENHANCED_ECOMMERCE'],
 'DATA_LAYER_NAME' => $arParams['DATA_LAYER_NAME'],
 'BRAND_PROPERTY' => $arParams['BRAND_PROPERTY'],
 'MESS_BTN_BUY' => $arParams['~MESS_BTN_BUY'],
 'MESS_BTN_DETAIL' => $arParams['~MESS_BTN_DETAIL'],
 'MESS_BTN_COMPARE' => $arParams['~MESS_BTN_COMPARE'],
 'MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE' => $arParams['~MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE'],
 'MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET' => $arParams['~MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET'],
 'MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE' => $arParams['~MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE']
);

$obName = 'ob'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', 'x', $this->GetEditAreaId($navParams['NavNum']));
$containerName = 'container-'.$navParams['NavNum'];

$themeClass = isset($arParams['TEMPLATE_THEME']) ? ' bx-'.$arParams['TEMPLATE_THEME'] : '';

?>
<div class="catalog_right"> <? // wrapper ?>
    <h1>Название шампуня</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Предприятие «Вереск» было создано в 1993 году на базе оборонного предприятия ОАО «Искра».
            Изначальная задача, которую поставил перед собой коллектив созданного общества – наладить
            выпуск мини-станций нового поколения для спутникового телевидения. Очень скоро эта продукция
            стала популярной, крупные поставки станций были сделаны на Таймыр и в Эвенкию.</p>
    </div>
 <ul class="regular_catalog">
 <?


 if ($showTopPager)
 {
  ?>
  <div class="row mb-4">
   <div class="col text-center" data-pagination-num="<?=$navParams['NavNum']?>">
    <!-- pagination-container -->
    <?=$arResult['NAV_STRING']?>
    <!-- pagination-container -->
   </div>
  </div>
  <?
 }
 //endregion

 //region Description
 if (($arParams['HIDE_SECTION_DESCRIPTION'] !== 'Y') && !empty($arResult['DESCRIPTION']))
 {
  ?>
  <div class="row mb-4">
   <div class="col catalog-section-description">
    <p><?=$arResult['DESCRIPTION']?></p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <?
 }
 //endregion
 ?>
   <?
   if (!empty($arResult['ITEMS']) && !empty($arResult['ITEM_ROWS']))
   {
    $areaIds = array();

    foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as $item)
    {
     $uniqueId = $item['ID'].'_'.md5($this->randString().$component->getAction());
     $areaIds[$item['ID']] = $this->GetEditAreaId($uniqueId);
     $this->AddEditAction($uniqueId, $item['EDIT_LINK'], $elementEdit);
     $this->AddDeleteAction($uniqueId, $item['DELETE_LINK'], $elementDelete, $elementDeleteParams);
    }

    foreach ($arResult['ITEM_ROWS'] as $rowData)
    {
     $rowItems = array_splice($arResult['ITEMS'], 0, $rowData['COUNT']);
     ?>
     <!--<div  data-entity="items-row">-->
      <?
      switch ($rowData['VARIANT'])
      {
       case 0:
        ?>
<!--        <div class="product_item">-->
         <?
         $item = reset($rowItems);
         $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
          'bitrix:catalog.item',
          'bootstrap_v4',
          array(
           'RESULT' => array(
            'ITEM' => $item,
            'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$item['ID']],
            'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
            'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
            'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
            'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'N',
            'SCALABLE' => 'N'
           ),
           'PARAMS' => $generalParams
            + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$item['IBLOCK_ID']])
          ),
          $component,
          array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
         );
         ?>
        <!--</div>-->
        <?
        break;

       case 1:
        foreach ($rowItems as $item)
        {
         ?>
         <div class="col-6 product-item-big-card">
          <?
          $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
           'bitrix:catalog.item',
           'bootstrap_v4',
           array(
            'RESULT' => array(
             'ITEM' => $item,
             'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$item['ID']],
             'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
             'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
             'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
             'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'N',
             'SCALABLE' => 'N'
            ),
            'PARAMS' => $generalParams
             + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$item['IBLOCK_ID']])
           ),
           $component,
           array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
          );
          ?>
         </div>
         <?
        }
        break;

       case 2:
        foreach ($rowItems as $item)
        {
         ?>
         <li class="rci" data-entity="<?=$containerName?>">
          <?
          $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
           'bitrix:catalog.item',
           '.default',
           array(
            'RESULT' => array(
             'ITEM' => $item,
             'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$item['ID']],
             'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
             'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
             'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
             'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'Y',
             'SCALABLE' => 'N'
            ),
            'PARAMS' => $generalParams
             + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$item['IBLOCK_ID']])
           ),
           $component,
           array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
          );
          ?>
         </li>
         <?
        }
        break;

       case 3:
        foreach ($rowItems as $item)
        {
         ?>
         <div class="col-6 col-md-3 product-item-small-card">
          <?
          $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
           'bitrix:catalog.item',
           'bootstrap_v4',
           array(
            'RESULT' => array(
             'ITEM' => $item,
             'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$item['ID']],
             'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
             'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
             'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
             'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'N',
             'SCALABLE' => 'N'
            ),
            'PARAMS' => $generalParams
             + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$item['IBLOCK_ID']])
           ),
           $component,
           array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
          );
          ?>
         </div>
         <?
        }
        break;

       case 4:
        $rowItemsCount = count($rowItems);
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 product-item-big-card">
         <?
         $item = array_shift($rowItems);
         $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
          'bitrix:catalog.item',
          'bootstrap_v4',
          array(
           'RESULT' => array(
            'ITEM' => $item,
            'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$item['ID']],
            'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
            'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
            'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
            'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'Y',
            'SCALABLE' => 'Y'
           ),
           'PARAMS' => $generalParams
            + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$item['IBLOCK_ID']])
          ),
          $component,
          array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
         );
         unset($item);
         ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 product-item-small-card">
         <div class="row">
          <?
          for ($i = 0; $i < $rowItemsCount - 1; $i++)
          {
           ?>
           <div class="col-6">
            <?
            $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
             'bitrix:catalog.item',
             'bootstrap_v4',
             array(
              'RESULT' => array(
               'ITEM' => $rowItems[$i],
               'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$rowItems[$i]['ID']],
               'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
               'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
               'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
               'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'N',
               'SCALABLE' => 'N'
              ),
              'PARAMS' => $generalParams
               + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$rowItems[$i]['IBLOCK_ID']])
             ),
             $component,
             array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
            );
            ?>
           </div>
           <?
          }
          ?>
         </div>
        </div>
        <?
        break;

       case 5:
        $rowItemsCount = count($rowItems);
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 product-item-small-card">
         <div class="row">
          <?
          for ($i = 0; $i < $rowItemsCount - 1; $i++)
          {
           ?>
           <div class="col-6">
            <?
            $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
             'bitrix:catalog.item',
             'bootstrap_v4',
             array(
              'RESULT' => array(
               'ITEM' => $rowItems[$i],
               'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$rowItems[$i]['ID']],
               'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
               'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
               'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
               'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'N',
               'SCALABLE' => 'N'
              ),
              'PARAMS' => $generalParams
               + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$rowItems[$i]['IBLOCK_ID']])
             ),
             $component,
             array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
            );
            ?>
           </div>
           <?
          }
          ?>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 product-item-big-card">
         <?
         $item = end($rowItems);
         $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
          'bitrix:catalog.item',
          'bootstrap_v4',
          array(
           'RESULT' => array(
            'ITEM' => $item,
            'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$item['ID']],
            'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
            'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
            'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
            'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'Y',
            'SCALABLE' => 'Y'
           ),
           'PARAMS' => $generalParams
            + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$item['IBLOCK_ID']])
          ),
          $component,
          array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
         );
         unset($item);
         ?>
        </div>
        <?
        break;

       case 6:
        foreach ($rowItems as $item)
        {
         ?>
         <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 product-item-small-card">
          <?
          $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
           'bitrix:catalog.item',
           'bootstrap_v4',
           array(
            'RESULT' => array(
             'ITEM' => $item,
             'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$item['ID']],
             'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
             'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
             'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
             'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'N',
             'SCALABLE' => 'N'
            ),
            'PARAMS' => $generalParams
             + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$item['IBLOCK_ID']])
           ),
           $component,
           array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
          );
          ?>
         </div>
         <?
        }

        break;

       case 7:
        $rowItemsCount = count($rowItems);
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 product-item-big-card">
         <?
         $item = array_shift($rowItems);
         $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
          'bitrix:catalog.item',
          'bootstrap_v4',
          array(
           'RESULT' => array(
            'ITEM' => $item,
            'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$item['ID']],
            'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
            'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
            'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
            'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'Y',
            'SCALABLE' => 'Y'
           ),
           'PARAMS' => $generalParams
            + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$item['IBLOCK_ID']])
          ),
          $component,
          array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
         );
         unset($item);
         ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 product-item-small-card">
         <div class="row">
          <?
          for ($i = 0; $i < $rowItemsCount - 1; $i++)
          {
           ?>
           <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            <?
            $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
             'bitrix:catalog.item',
             'bootstrap_v4',
             array(
              'RESULT' => array(
               'ITEM' => $rowItems[$i],
               'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$rowItems[$i]['ID']],
               'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
               'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
               'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
               'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'N',
               'SCALABLE' => 'N'
              ),
              'PARAMS' => $generalParams
               + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$rowItems[$i]['IBLOCK_ID']])
             ),
             $component,
             array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
            );
            ?>
           </div>
           <?
          }
          ?>
         </div>
        </div>
        <?
        break;

       case 8:
        $rowItemsCount = count($rowItems);
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 product-item-small-card">
         <div class="row">
          <?
          for ($i = 0; $i < $rowItemsCount - 1; $i++)
          {
           ?>
           <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            <?
            $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
             'bitrix:catalog.item',
             'bootstrap_v4',
             array(
              'RESULT' => array(
               'ITEM' => $rowItems[$i],
               'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$rowItems[$i]['ID']],
               'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
               'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
               'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
               'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'N',
               'SCALABLE' => 'N'
              ),
              'PARAMS' => $generalParams
               + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$rowItems[$i]['IBLOCK_ID']])
             ),
             $component,
             array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
            );
            ?>
           </div>
           <?
          }
          ?>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 product-item-big-card">
         <?
         $item = end($rowItems);
         $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
          'bitrix:catalog.item',
          'bootstrap_v4',
          array(
           'RESULT' => array(
            'ITEM' => $item,
            'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$item['ID']],
            'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
            'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
            'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
            'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'Y',
            'SCALABLE' => 'Y'
           ),
           'PARAMS' => $generalParams
            + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$item['IBLOCK_ID']])
          ),
          $component,
          array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
         );
         unset($item);
         ?>
        </div>
        <?
        break;

       case 9:
        foreach ($rowItems as $item)
        {
         ?>
         <div class="col product-item-line-card">
          <? $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent('bitrix:catalog.item', 'bootstrap_v4', array(
            'RESULT' => array(
             'ITEM' => $item,
             'AREA_ID' => $areaIds[$item['ID']],
             'TYPE' => $rowData['TYPE'],
             'BIG_LABEL' => 'N',
             'BIG_DISCOUNT_PERCENT' => 'N',
             'BIG_BUTTONS' => 'N'
            ),
            'PARAMS' => $generalParams
             + array('SKU_PROPS' => $arResult['SKU_PROPS'][$item['IBLOCK_ID']])
           ),
           $component,
           array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
          );
          ?>
         </div>
         <?
        }

        break;
      }
      ?>
     </div>
     <?
    }
    unset($generalParams, $rowItems);

   }
   else
   {
    // load css for bigData/deferred load
    $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
     'bitrix:catalog.item',
     'bootstrap_v4',
     array(),
     $component,
     array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
    );
   }
   ?>
   <!-- items-container -->
  <!--</li>-->
  <?

  //region LazyLoad Button
  if ($showLazyLoad)
  {
   ?>
   <div class="text-center mb-4" data-entity="lazy-<?=$containerName?>">
    <button type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-md"
      style="margin: 15px;"
      data-use="show-more-<?=$navParams['NavNum']?>">
       <?=$arParams['MESS_BTN_LAZY_LOAD']?>
    </button>
   </div>
   <?
  }
  //endregion

  //region Pagination
  if ($showBottomPager)
  {
   ?>
   <div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col text-center" data-pagination-num="<?=$navParams['NavNum']?>">
     <!-- pagination-container -->
     <?=$arResult['NAV_STRING']?>
     <!-- pagination-container -->
    </div>
   </div>
   <?
  }
  //endregion

  $signer = new \Bitrix\Main\Security\Sign\Signer;
  $signedTemplate = $signer->sign($templateName, 'catalog.section');
  $signedParams = $signer->sign(base64_encode(serialize($arResult['ORIGINAL_PARAMETERS'])), 'catalog.section');
  ?>
  <script>
   BX.message({
    BTN_MESSAGE_BASKET_REDIRECT: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_BTN_MESSAGE_BASKET_REDIRECT')?>',
    BASKET_URL: '<?=$arParams['BASKET_URL']?>',
    ADD_TO_BASKET_OK: '<?=GetMessageJS('ADD_TO_BASKET_OK')?>',
    TITLE_ERROR: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_TITLE_ERROR')?>',
    TITLE_BASKET_PROPS: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_TITLE_BASKET_PROPS')?>',
    TITLE_SUCCESSFUL: '<?=GetMessageJS('ADD_TO_BASKET_OK')?>',
    BASKET_UNKNOWN_ERROR: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_BASKET_UNKNOWN_ERROR')?>',
    BTN_MESSAGE_SEND_PROPS: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_BTN_MESSAGE_SEND_PROPS')?>',
    BTN_MESSAGE_CLOSE: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_BTN_MESSAGE_CLOSE')?>',
    BTN_MESSAGE_CLOSE_POPUP: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_BTN_MESSAGE_CLOSE_POPUP')?>',
    COMPARE_MESSAGE_OK: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_MESS_COMPARE_OK')?>',
    COMPARE_UNKNOWN_ERROR: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_MESS_COMPARE_UNKNOWN_ERROR')?>',
    COMPARE_TITLE: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_MESS_COMPARE_TITLE')?>',
    PRICE_TOTAL_PREFIX: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_PRICE_TOTAL_PREFIX')?>',
    RELATIVE_QUANTITY_MANY: '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($arParams['MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_MANY'])?>',
    RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FEW: '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($arParams['MESS_RELATIVE_QUANTITY_FEW'])?>',
    BTN_MESSAGE_COMPARE_REDIRECT: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_BTN_MESSAGE_COMPARE_REDIRECT')?>',
    BTN_MESSAGE_LAZY_LOAD: '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($arParams['MESS_BTN_LAZY_LOAD'])?>',
    BTN_MESSAGE_LAZY_LOAD_WAITER: '<?=GetMessageJS('CT_BCS_CATALOG_BTN_MESSAGE_LAZY_LOAD_WAITER')?>',
    SITE_ID: '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($component->getSiteId())?>'
   });
   var <?=$obName?> = new JCCatalogSectionComponent({
    siteId: '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($component->getSiteId())?>',
    componentPath: '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($componentPath)?>',
    navParams: <?=CUtil::PhpToJSObject($navParams)?>,
    deferredLoad: false, // enable it for deferred load
    initiallyShowHeader: '<?=!empty($arResult['ITEM_ROWS'])?>',
    bigData: <?=CUtil::PhpToJSObject($arResult['BIG_DATA'])?>,
    lazyLoad: !!'<?=$showLazyLoad?>',
    loadOnScroll: !!'<?=($arParams['LOAD_ON_SCROLL'] === 'Y')?>',
    template: '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($signedTemplate)?>',
    ajaxId: '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($arParams['AJAX_ID'])?>',
    parameters: '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($signedParams)?>',
    container: '<?=$containerName?>'
   });
  </script>


 </ul>
</div> <? //end wrapper?>
<!-- component-end -->
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Внутри `<ul>` не должно быть ничего кроме `<li>` (вот документация http://htmlbook.ru/html/ul ) т.е. не `<script>` ни `<div>`. Если нужны `<div>` вставьте их в `<li>` а скрипт вынесите наружу.
+ может быть php ошибка где то после объявления `<ul>` тогда браузер возможно авто до закроет тег, смотрите код страницы в инспекторе кода браузера (ну скорее всего проблема из за того что много всего вставлено в `ul` лишнего).
(Грубо говоря по какому то условию (у вас таких много) вы внутрь `<ul>` добавляете `<div>` браузер считает это как будто вы не закрыли `</ul>` (забыли) и авто закрывает тег ставит `</ul>` отсюда и проблема )